# upshot js vs. breeze js

Tags: breeze, single-page-application, upshot

Is upshot js under active development?  All upshot articles have been written in March 2012.
Is upshot js stable?  Breeze seems to be under active development.

Is it ready for production?  The vs spa application template was added and later removed.  when will it be re-added?  I'm guessing it will be re-added with upshot since upshot is tied to ms.

```
public class TodosController : ApiController {

    readonly EFContextProvider<TodosContext> contextProvider = 
        new EFContextProvider<TodosContext>("TodosContext");

    // ~/api/todos/Metadata 
    [AcceptVerbs("GET")]
    public string Metadata() {
        return contextProvider.Metadata();
    }

    // ~/api/todos/Todos
    // ~/api/todos/Todos?$filter=IsArchived%20eq%20false&$orderby=CreatedAt 
    [AcceptVerbs("GET")]
    public IQueryable<TodoItem> Todos() {
        return contextProvider.Context.Todos;
    }

    // ~/api/todos/SaveChanges
    [AcceptVerbs("POST")]
    public SaveResult SaveChanges(JArray saveBundle) {
        return contextProvider.SaveChanges(saveBundle);
    }

    // other miscellaneous actions of no interest to us here
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Upshot is dead according to the latest roadmap: [ASP.NET Webstack Roadmap](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Roadmap)

I guess for now, [Breeze](http://www.breezejs.com/home) is it. I wish they added a larger sample than the classic ToDo so we can see what it's really capable of.

Answer (score 10):

Clive - I see you posted a snapshot of the Web API controller from the Breeze Todo sample. Happy you're looking at it.

No one has heard from upshot in ages. It may be dead or it may merely be moribund with a chance for revival someday. It sure isn't "alive" in any practical sense.

Breeze, on the other hand, is very much under active development. HTH

Answer (score 2):

We had been using upshot extensively (for at least half a year) in a fairly big project and after some serious issues we decided to drop it - in my opinion it is **not** ready for production use yet, unless your application is very very simple (hence the example todo app and delivery tracker example).

Heck, their last meaningful commit was more than half a year ago (early 2012) and the code is big, complicated and is filled with "NYI" (not yet implemented) comments.

Answer (score 1):

Juan is spot on. Upshot is dead.

"Earlier this year the Beta version of Visual Studio 2012 included a template that was designed for building “single page applications” using Upshot.js and a special Web API-based DataController that provided support for insert, update, and delete operations using the unit of work pattern with transaction support. We are not currently continuing work on that template or Upshot.js. We want to first focus on improving the development experience with existing popular JavaScript libraries and in future versions we will revisit this decision and see if additional libraries are needed to round out the SPA experience."

Colin Blair is gives his thoughts on the [RIA Services blog the WCF RIA Services is Dead, Long Live WCF RIA Services](http://www.riaservicesblog.net/Blog/post/WCF-RIA-Services-is-Dead-Long-Live-WCF-RIA-Services.aspx) post.